# ReportViewer not showing RDLC report

Tags: c#, winforms

Here Powerfail_101 is the DB Table name,stores the Powerfail data.The RDLC report not showing any data on ReportViewer.ReportViewer with Empty data.

```
private void GenerateReport(object dt) 
{
    if (this.InvokeRequired)
    {
        MyDelegate mydelegate = new MyDelegate(GenerateReport);
        this.Invoke(mydelegate, new object[] { dt });
    }
    else
    {
        DataTable table = (DataTable)dt;
        if (table.Rows.Count != 0)
        {

            table.TableName = "table";

            // Clear the rows to clear any previous data.
            DataLogger_DBDataSet.PowerFail_101.Rows.Clear();

            DataLogger_DBDataSet.Tables.Add(table);

            string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
            string reportPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(exeFolder, @"Report\PowrfailReport.rdlc");

            reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear();
            this.reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = reportPath;


            ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource("DataSet1", DataLogger_DBDataSet.Tables["table"]);
            reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
            this.reportViewer1.RefreshReport();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please refer this link how to use ReportViewer and the steps to assign data source you might have missed https://www.mindstick.com/Articles/1118/using-reportviewer-in-winforms-c-sharp

Comment: I have removed version-10 ReportViewer and added reference for version-11 ReportViewer.But still I am getting reportViewer with blank,no data..

Comment: plz get me rid of dis

Comment: why you set your report path twice, this line is not required. 
 reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportPath = reportPath;

Answer (score 1):

I think you have not gone step by step as the link in my comment

**Example**

```
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Clear(); //clear report
reportViewer1.LocalReport.ReportEmbeddedResource = reportPath; // bind reportviewer with .rdlc

Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource rds = new 
Microsoft.Reporting.WinForms.ReportDataSource("DataSet1", DataLogger_DBDataSet.Tables["table"]); // set the datasource
reportViewer1.LocalReport.DataSources.Add(rds);
rds.Value = DataLogger_DBDataSet.Tables["table"];  //also this line may be required

reportViewer1.LocalReport.Refresh();
reportViewer1.RefreshReport(); // refresh report
```

Comment: No..I did.I followed the link